Application thats compatible with android that allows you to access the wifi signals around you and constructs its own
Can we develop a application thats compatible with android that allows you to access the wifi signals around you and constructs its own?
By continuously encryption data by the wifi signal by encrypting with enhanced AI in formulating the strongest wifi signal
